# Flutter custom bar chart

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

I'm trying to create a custom chart in Flutter.
Here is what I'm trying to achieve -

[image: Custom chart]

I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to replace the label (string) with a widget?
   Is there an easy get-around without using a row under the chart?
2. What's the best way to draw the percentage and the numeric value inside the chart?